# set multiple view with dynamic size in scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am getting problem while adding autolayout because i am not able to give autolayout i am very well when its come to logic but not in autolayout UI

So i share link here i want set Uiview like this its in android but i want to do in iOS Swift

**Link**
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UffZOLdZoQpq7GnA0dw6TKDa_NZanDkc

please help me to get idea how can i do this please watch video and tell me how can i do this give me some idea about this

Comment: don't use uiscrollview, with collectionview you can easily achieve this functionality

Comment: but problem is that when facebook and twitter will logout and i will login with google then their detail view is not come on top so how can i manage that thing

Comment: you mean user login any social media account, so that account will come on first or top in ui?

Comment: yes means user login with gmail first then gmail detail view comes top then login with linkedin then its detail come to second means user can login any social media but detail view arrange by sequence of login understand or not please tell me

Comment: okay, simply collectionview is manage by array. so when any social account get log in, just put that login info in top of your collectionview array n reload your view.

Comment: ok thats fine but when i login first google than its come on top then i do twitter then how can i set in second?

Comment: if u don't mind then please talk in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181315/discussion-between-pratik-prajapati-and-vishal).

Comment: Hello any one please give me solution for this